# How to detect pattern in cells of data frame and convert them to NA using R?

Tags: r, na, missing-data

I have a data frame (3,000 rows and 30 columns) with many cells containing text error messages within the same cell that contain values. Dummy data that resembles my data frame:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- NULL
x$A <- runif(100, -1, 1)
x <- as.data.frame(x)
x$A[round(runif(50, 1, 100))] <- sapply(x$A, substring, 1, 6)
set.seed(223)
x$A[round(runif(40, 1, 100))] <- paste(x$A, "- Error text")
set.seed(323)
x$A[round(runif(20, 1, 100))] <- paste(x$A, "- Some error texts are longer")
# same for column B
x$B <- runif(100, -1, 1)
x$B[round(runif(30, 1, 100))] <- sapply(x$B, substring, 1, 5)
set.seed(423)
x$B[round(runif(30, 1, 100))] <- paste(x$B, "- Error text")
set.seed(553)
x$B[round(runif(60, 1, 100))] <- paste(x$B, "- Some error texts are longer")
```

I wish to turn the cells that contain error texts into NA, like this:

```
                                A                                                B
1              -0.424844959750772                               -0.160817455966026
2                          -0.172                                               NA
3                -0.1820461563766                                               NA
4                              NA                                            -0.10
5               0.880934568587691                                               NA
6              -0.908887001220137                                               NA
```

I have used `x$A[x$A  %in% c(" -")] <- NA` which obviously applies only to hits on whole strings. I had better luck with `str_detect(x$A, " -")` of the `stringr`pkg which is still not optimal as I have to change the column names manually; but **this outputs a TRUE/FALSE hit list and I am not sure how to proceed from here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R using `sapply` with `grepl` :

```
x[sapply(x, grepl, pattern = ' -')] <- NA
```

You might then want to change the type of columns.

```
x <- type.convert(x)
```

---

To understand how this works we can take a smaller example.

```
x <- data.frame(A = c('-0.4248', '-0.172', '-0.363 - Error text', '0.880'), 
                B = c('-0.160', '-0.63 - Some error texts are longer', 
                      '-0.882 - Error text', '-0.10'))
x

#                    A                                   B
#1             -0.4248                              -0.160
#2              -0.172 -0.63 - Some error texts are longer
#3 -0.363 - Error text                 -0.882 - Error text
#4               0.880                               -0.10
```

`grepl` returns `TRUE` where it finds the pattern.

```
sapply(x, grepl, pattern = ' -')

#         A     B
#[1,] FALSE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE  TRUE
#[3,]  TRUE  TRUE
#[4,] FALSE FALSE
```

and we turn those `TRUE` values to `NA`.

```
x[sapply(x, grepl, pattern = ' -')] <- NA
x

#        A      B
#1 -0.4248 -0.160
#2  -0.172   <NA>
#3    <NA>   <NA>
#4   0.880  -0.10
```

Comment: This was excellent. Can you explain what the code is doing here?

Comment: I added some explanation with a shorter example to explain the process here.